# Loading a deployed ONNX model only once

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, onnx

I have a big Machine learning/ Computer vision project that is using an ONNX model, using python.
the project takes around 3 seconds (locally) just to load the model + inference.

> Time taken to load onnx model :  0.2702977657318115
> Time taken for onnx inference 1.673530101776123
> Time taken for onnx inference 0.7677013874053955

After deploying the project, this loading time is always initiated with each individual hit on the server.

for example, if 4 users request at once, all the results will take around 30 seconds. when having only 1 request, it takes only around 10 second.

**Problem**
Is there any way to load the onnx model only once when initializing the server, not with every and each post request?

> I tried async.io

it helped queuing the requests, but still, the last request will have to wait 30 seconds for the results, even though, the CPU usage is not at 100%.
I am not sure the solution to my problem is loading the onnx model only once, or multithreading or am I doing the best thing by applying async.io to my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to load the model and then doing the inference every time that you have a request?

You should load once and keep the session throughout the time life of the inference process. You could also look into execution providers that come with ONNXruntime to try and speed up the inference time like `CUDA, tensorRT`...

```
import onnxruntime as ort

def load_model(onnx_model_path):
    inference_session = ort.InferenceSession(
            onnx_model_path,
        )
    
     # get input and output names of model layers for inference placeholder
     inputs = inference_session.get_inputs()[0].name
     outputs = [
            output.name for output in inference_session.get_outputs()
        ]

     return inference_session, {"inputs": inputs, "outputs": outputs}


def main():
    inf_session, input_output_dict = load_model("your/model.onnx")

    while True:
        inf_session.run(input_output_dict["outputs"], {
                str(input_output_dict[inputs]): your_array_input})
```

Comment: This was the first step to help me optimize my code. Eventually, the inference time is in the main prediction process that can not be initialized in the beginning of the session only; it must be performed with every request.
However, I eventually solved my problem by creating a FastApi api to handle the requests, better than a pure python solution. Thank you for your time and effort.